# Is is possible avoid deleting a user via SCIM provisioning when AccountEnabled=false in an Azure AD Enterprise Application?

Tags: azure-active-directory, scim

My Azure AD admin have created an Enterprise App for me and I'm Configuration Owner for it.

The app Provisioning is setup to:

- Provision Azure Active Directory Groups
- Provision Azure Active Directory Users

to my SCIM server.

The setup is working fine, users are created via and groups are updated also.

My problem is that in my company workflow when a consultant contract is renewed the user's `AccountEnabled` property is set to `false` and then later re-enabled with `AccountEnabled=true`, this is translating right now into a Delete / Create via SCIM in my app.

My impression was that `AccountEnabled=false` would translate to a `isSoftDeleted=true` (as mentioned in [Customizing user provisioning attribute-mappings for SaaS application in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/customize-application-attributes#what-you-should-know)) and that in turn will translate to a [SCIM Disable User request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups#disable-user) because of the attribute mapping settings of the app is to map the Azure Active Directory Attribute `Not([IsSoftDeleted])` to `active` attribute in the app.

But it's not disabling the user it's deleting it.

The user resides in a on-premises Active Directory then synced to Azure AD.

All the information that I could find (like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/6670/azure-ad-scim-not-sending-delete-requests.html)) suggest that a SCIM Delete should only happened after 30 days when a user is hard deleted and not when `AccountEnabled=false` so I guess it may be another factor at play.

So, **how do I stop Azure AD from issuing Delete user for disabled users in my app?**.

EDIT: I tested with a local user in Azure AD (not synced from the on-premises AD) and with that user when the user is disabled it triggers an update user not a delete. So it must be related with synced users only (I'm still troubleshooting)

Answer (score 1):

1. Certain applications don't support soft deletes so the Azure AD provisioning service sends a delete in place of an update. What app are you using?
2. The attribute mapping blade allows you to de-select delete as an option, do the deletes stop when you do that?
3. I recommend keeping the attribute mappings as close to the default as possible.

Comment: It's a  custom non-gallery app developed by me (SCIM server also developed by me) , the SCIM server supports disabling a user. But maybe Azure AD does NOT know that. Is there any  config parameter to tell Azure Ad that this app supports soft deletes?
I can de-select the delete checkbox but will that stop all deletes I believe (no hard deletion) , I want hard deletion -> scim deletion, soft deletion -> scim disable user.

Comment: I've tried using a local Azure AD user (instead of a user synced from the on-premises Active Directory) and there it works. I mean when the user account is disabled in Azure AD the SCIM provisioning updates the user with `active=false`. It seems that something special happens with the synced users

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "not" function and using the default attribute mappings. The default mapping uses a switch statement to map false to true and true to false. It sends the request as a string rather than a boolean.

Comment: The `Not([IsSoftDeleted])` is correct, so that is `IsSoftDeleted=true` then `active=false`. You have a point, in that in a create request the active parameter is sent as a boolean `active: true` but in an update request is sent as a string `active: 'False'`. I handle both cases.